# Getting error when using symbols in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So the error is at `const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();`

It says `Object` is not iterable (cannot read property `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)`)

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Product.css';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';

function Product({ id, title, img, price, rating }) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const addToBasket = () => {
        dispatch({
            type:'ADD_TO_BASKET',
            item: {
                id: id,
                title: title,
                img: img,
                price: price,
                rating: rating
            },
        })
    };

    return ( 
        <div className="product">
            <div className="product__info">
                <p>{title} </p>
                <p className="product__price">
                    <small>$</small>
                    <strong>{price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="product__rating">
                    {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) => ( 
                    <p>⭐</p>
                    ))}
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src={img} />
            <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to basket</button>
        </div>
    )
}
`this is the StateProvider``import React from "react";
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, childern }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {childern}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: Please don't put additional info or code into comments. Instead, [edit] the question and add it there. Also, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format code blocks.

Comment: You should provide code for `useStateValue`

Comment: I did, please help